# mysql load data infile

Tags: mysql

i got to execute loads of the following queries

```
UPDATE translations SET translation = (SELECT description FROM content WHERE id = 10) WHERE id = 1;
```

Now, i use the load data infile to do inserts and replacements but what i want in esense is to update just 1 field for each row in that table with out messing with the keys. What could be the syntax for this, note that the queries affect existing rows only.

Thanx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Use [`CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) to create a temporary table.
- Then use `LOAD DATA INFILE` to populate that temporary table.
- Then execute your `UPDATE translations SET translation = ...` to set the 1 field from a SELECT of the temporary table, JOINed with the real table. example syntax below:

  ```
  UPDATE realTable, tmpTable 
    SET realTable.price = tmpTable.price 
    WHERE realTable.key = tmpTable.key
  ```